# Скрытые елементы при перезагрузке JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, форма

Есть 1 страничка с двумя формами. По умолчанию вторая форма скрыта.
При нажатии на кнопку форма 1 скрывается а форма 2 выводится на экран.
Прошу подсказать с помощью каких средств сделать так что бы после нажатия  кнопки и скрытия формы 1, юзер продолжал оставаться а форме 2 которая у него открыта.
Прощу подсказать возможно ли это реализовать на JS.

Comment: ничего не понятно, ты говоришь что 2 форма выводится для юзера и следом спрашиваешь как сделать чтобы она была открыта, и покажи что за кнопка и вообще пример твое реализации

Answer (score 1):

Дмитрий, необходимо подробней описать проблему. С примерами кода и прочим.
Ну а пока, помните мем:

- У Вас изначально была какая-то тактика и Вы её придерживались?
- У меня изначально была какая-то тактика и я её придерживался.

Так что, какой вопрос, таков и ответ, получайте:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1">что-то в форме1</form>
<form id="form2" style="display: none;">что-то в форме2 (по-умолчанию скрыта)</form>
<button id="someButton">Какая-то кнопка</button>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        const form1Element = document.querySelector('#form1');
        const form2Element = document.querySelector('#form2');
        const someButtonElement = document.querySelector('#someButton');

        someButtonElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log('click', form1Element.style.display);
            form1Element.style.display = 'none';
            console.log('click', form1Element.style.display);
            form2Element.style.display = 'block';
        })
    })
</script>
</body>
```